Retrieve stored JSON string as a column of Delta table using Scala and Apache Spark
Problem To Solve
Need to extract json string from delta table and parse it eventually. show function can be used to see the data but it needs to be extracted into map or case class for processing.
The data is inserted from json file to delta table. The column in the table is of type String. In this process only data is stored in the delta table column and not the key values from json array. So select query returns partial data so to say. Is this default behavior of delta table ?
e.g.
The data to store { "name" : "Sample"}
What actually gets stored : { "Sample"}
Background
Already referred to following SO questions and followed the instructions there but could not find the solution
Question 1
Question 2

Insertion Step

Data was inserted into delta table from a json file
One of the field is json array and it is supposed to be inserted as is
    val jsonData = spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .option("mode",
        "PERMISSIVE"
      ).option(
        "dropFieldIfAllNull",
        false
      ).json(FILE_PATH)
      .createOrReplaceTempView("data")

    val data = spark.sql("""SELECT * from Data""")

    val inputDataFrame = data
      .select(
        col("Id"),
        col("Version"),
        col("StartDate"),
        col("EndDate"),
        explode(col("Configuration")).alias(
          "Config"
        ) 
      )
      .withColumn("ConfigId", col("Config.Id"))
      .
      .
      .
      .toDF
      
      val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(.....)

      deltaTable
      .as("Config") 
      .merge(
             inputDataFrame.as("input"),
  
      )
      .whenMatched
      .update(
        Map(
            "ConfigData" -> col("input.Config"),
        )
      )
      .whenNotMatched
      .insert(
        Map(
          "ConfigData" -> col("input.Config"),
        )
      )
      .execute()
  }


Select Step

After running select query the data shows up without keys and only values from the json string inserted

Read Step

Method 1
val arrayOffStringSchema = ArrayType(StringType)

var configData = df.select("Config").as[String]
configData.show(false) // shows Config column and data without keys
                                         
var desiredData = configData.withColumn("Config",from_json(col("Config"), arrayofStringSchema))
desiredData.show(false) // shows null

Method 2
val json_schema = spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .option(
        "mode",
        "PERMISSIVE"
      ) 
      .option(
        "dropFieldIfAllNull",
        false
      ).json(df.select("Config").as[String]).schema
var config = configData.withColumn("Config", from_json(col("Config"),json_schema))
config.show(false) // shows Config column and data without keys
config.printSchema() // Shows following

/*
root
 |-- Config: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
*/


Platform
Scala 2.12.18
Apache Spark 3.5.1
What is missing here ? Is there problem in inserting or there is some other way to achieve this ?
EDIT 1
Apparently when the data is stored the schema is inferred automatically and it is not stored in the delta table. So while fetching data, no idea where does the schema come from. Basically a Map is needed which will enable to fetch fields from the json string stored as column in delta table.

As of now this question is not really answerable. Because we don't know the expected behaviour that you wanted to implement. As might think that this describes your requirement, but it does not. I have read this question multiple times in last 2 days... but I still don't understand anything. Can you give a simple example of what your input data was, what you wanted to get and what you are getting ?

For example this line here -  In this process only data is stored in the delta table column and not the key values from json array. It does not mean anything. What do you mean by "only data is stored" and "not the key values from json array" ? What was the json array ? What is the data as per you, if it is not the key-vals from Json ? And why are we talking about key-values in context of Json array ?

The to_json and from_json methods came handy for me in this situation.  The delta table column is of type String and the json as read from a file was being stored there. In this process the schema was being striped off. So for reading using from_json method was tricky as there was no schema. So I corrected the insert mechanism using to_json and not json schema is available hence from_json method gives me dataframe from which required fields could be chosen

let me explain the problem in nutshell
The data from a json file is being read and inserted into Delta Table column.
The column is of the type String
It was observed that when the dataframe containing json data is as is inserted into Delta table column, it automatically infers the schema and all the keys from the json structure are dropped and only values are stored
It made difficult to parse the data as it was read later from the delta table column.
Solution
to_json : used to convert dataframe column to json and stored into delta table column
from_json : used to convert dataframe column to structured json
val json_schema = spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .option(
        "mode",
        "PERMISSIVE"
      ) 
      .option(
        "dropFieldIfAllNull",
        false
      ).json(df.select("Config").as[String]).schema

var struct_json = levers.withColumn("StructuredConfig", from_json(col("Config"),json_schema))

struct_json.printSchema // shows desired schema

Now when StructuredConfig.name or StructuredConfig.id can be selected from the dataframe which was not possible previously
